# C# Automation of Bloomberg Request Builder

Tags: sftp, bloomberg

I have a requirement where I need to download the report from Request builder application(Desktop Application) provided by Bloomberg. Using SFTP, Request builder connects to Bloomberg terminal and fetch the results. Clicking on "Download Excel" option in Request Builder will download the results from Bloomberg in excel. I have not seen the application yet. Is there any API which connects to Request builder application. If anyone have any pointer, it will be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an enterprise license? I can follow up with some specific code, if you need, but the RequestBuilder runs on .req files, which are essentially text, so for applications where we allow people to change tickers for example, we create those .req files on submission by the user, then upload with sftp through Python to the Bloomberg server, and then enterprise runs it, and we receive the raw files back and then parse the data as needed, including output to excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch Bloomberg DL data using Web Services instead of Request Builder over sftp. Code examples in DotNet (C#) and Java are available on the terminal (DLSD).